# When to use ARIA role attribute

Tags: wai-aria

I'm attempting to make my website compliant with WCAG. Is a custom radiobutton that overlays the native HTML control with a styled div the proper use case for the `role="radio"` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which element will receive the keyboard focus.  If focus goes to the native element (`<input type="radio">`), then the screen reader will announce it properly and you're good.  If it goes to your custom element, then you'd need an ARIA role (and a role for the container too, `role="radiogroup"`).

Note that if focus goes to the native radio, then make sure you custom element is hidden (`aria-hidden="true"`) from the screen reader.  It would be confusing to be able to put the screen reader focus on both radios.